# How to set HTTPS redirection to HTTP 8000 port in an ec2 AWS?

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53

I have an Angular app working fine with a custom domain on AWS Amplify, well, this app is connected with a NodeJS backend, located on an ec2 instance.

I am using HTTPS for the Angular app, and I also need to use HTTPS to the ec2 instance.

I have configured a Load Balancer to redirect HTTPS to HTTP port 8000, and added the Load Balancer to Route53 to use a custom domain, and here is when my problem come in.

When I do a http request it works fine, but when I do a https request this error throw in.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSDWT.png)

Comment: How did you setup redirection on the alb?

Comment: You shouldn't be using redirection on the load balancer. Redirecting HTTPS to HTTP is not what you want to do. You should configure a load balancer listener for HTTPS on port 443, and point it to a target group that sends request to port HTTP:8000 on your EC2 instance. That way the request between the browser and the load balancer is HTTPS, while the internal traffic between the load balancer and the EC2 instance will be HTTP.